# http multipart post request with json and an image with koush/ion library

Tags: java, android, ruby, json, http

I'm trying to post a multipart data consisting of **image** and **json object parameter** "status" from Android OS to Ruby rails server.
I'm doing an android version of a completed iOS app so the server side works.

But I can't seem to get it to work on android with or without any libraries.

On the server side, this has to be received for it to work.

```
 >>>> params: {"status"=>{"body"=>"Make love, not Warcraft. "}, 
"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f36a89e5738 
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140414-29241-gy4qeo>, @original_filename="iUEb2W9cnxG6", 
@content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; 
filename=\"iUEb2W9cnxG6\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "format"=>"json", 
"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"api/statuses", "version"=>"1"}
```

But when I do this, it doesn't work.

```
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonObject postbody = (JsonObject)jp.parse("{\"status\": { \"body\": \""+ text.getText().toString() +"\", \"venue\": null}}");

System.out.println("Start uploading image using Ion Library");


            Ion.with(it, The.url("/1/statuses"))
            .setHeader("uuid", The.uuid(it).toString())
            .setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
            .setMultipartParameter("status", postbody.toString())
            .setMultipartFile("image", "image/jpeg", selectedFile)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
               @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                   System.out.println("Posted result "+ e + " " + result+ The.url("/1/statuses"));
               }});
            }

        }
```

What I get from the server is basically parsing error.

```
I, [2014-04-14T17:21:01.411626 #29241]  INFO -- : Started POST "/1/statuses" for 64.179.216.50 at 2014-04-14 17:21:01 -0400
D, [2014-04-14T17:21:01.415493 #29241] DEBUG -- : Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

------------------------------806fe35005b7480e81c10fc5c7ce33ef
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"

{"body":"i h8 u","venue":null}
------------------------------806fe35005b7480e81c10fc5c7ce33ef
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="img.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

????E?ExifII*
?2?i???(SAMSUNGGT-I9500I9500UBUEMK12014:04:14 17:20:46HH?,??4"?'???0220?<?P?
d?l?
t?
|???    ?
??|?bH(???%??0100????8??(??? ?
                              <(?d2014:04:14 17:20:462014:04:14 17:20:46?d?d????d
?d?dASCIId?
           ?????????#??M?-?@??????????M?-?,??????????M?-???????????M?-???????????M?-????????????M?-????????????M?-???????????ĲX??-д\?????X.p/???P?00?????/?BO?
                           ??
???????????????!?o??P???P??????
???
   ???0?@?A?0F???????????????@?
                               ?????????#??M?-?@??????????M?-?,??????????M?-???????????M?-???????????M?-????????????M?-????????????M?-???????????ĲX??-д\?????X.p/???P?00?????/?BO?
                                               ??
???????????????!?o??P???P??????
???
   ???0?@?A?0F???????????????n)?p)?Ăf)?e)?g)?a)?h
A??i)???d)???u)???o)?O?x)??)???)???)???)?L??)???h?  (?A??c)??s)?
                                                                    ??)?#??)?(? pG??5?%?????? !??? ` !??@`` !????` !?`??`A?Y??? B???;???F?????????????????????????O?@p??
??M?@??(FP????*FhFP????jF(FO?????*FhFO?????jF(FO???|?*FhFO?????jF(FO???w?*FhFO???~?jF(FO???r?*FhFO???{?jF(FO???m?*FhFO???z?jF(FO???h?*FhFO???w?jF(FO???c?*FhFO??u?jF(FO??^?*FhFO??r?jF(FO??qH?X?O.
```

I have tried without the library and all kinds of stuff for the past 8 hours and researched for a long time. I still feel like I'm missing something so easy and obvious but I haven't done a lot of image post requests so far... Any solution with any library will be appreciated.

Edit: .setBodyParameter(....) was a typo and fixed to .setMultipartParameter(...)
That was the code that resulted in this result.
If someone could give me a piece of code that will do what I want to do, it'll be extremely appreciated.
Thank you internet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of setBodyParameter, use set setMultipartParameter. I'm not sure how you're invoking that, as that won't compile on my end.

What version of ion are you on? There was a fix to remove extraneous CRLF in multipart payloads a month ago:

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/commit/efb6c018bd15060e44086d4f76c3d419d26065ba

Comment: This is correct. I posted the wrong code that I ran to get the above result. My actual code was 

""replace""
.setBodyParameter with 

""this""
.setMultipartParameter("status",jsonObjectData.toString())

That resulted in the above result on the server side.
It would be extremely appreciated if you could give me an example of sending a json parameter with an image file data using Ion!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem;

instead of setting multipart file;
...
.setMultipartFile("image", "image/jpeg", fileToUpload)

setting filebody solved my problem.
...
.setFileBody(fileToUpload)